# Selecting a range of rows from R data frame

Tags: r

I have a data  frame with 1000 rows and I want to perform some operation on it with 100 rows at a time.
So, I am trying to find out how would I use a counter increment on the number of rows and select 100 rows at a time like 1 to 100, then 101 to 200... uptil 1000 and perform operation on each subset using a for loop. Can anyone please suggest what how can this be done as I could not find out a good method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @mrdwab is great and shows how to avoid a for loop.  But if you really must use a for loop (the biglm package would be one example where you might want to) then here is one approach:

```
for( i in seq(1,1000,by=100) ) {
  myfun( df[ i:(i+99), ] )
}
```

If the total number of rows is not a multiple of the block size then you might want something more like:

```
tmp <- seq( 1, nrow(df), by=100 )
tmp2 <- c( tail( tmp, -1)-1, nrow(df) )
n <- length(tmp)
out <- numeric(n)
for( i in seq_along(tmp) ) {
  out[i] <- myfun( df[ tmp[i]:tmp2[i], ] )
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An easy way would be to create a grouping variable, then use `split()` and `lapply()` to do whatever operations you need to.

Your grouping can be easily created using `rep()`.

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(1)
demo = data.frame(A = sample(300, 50, replace=TRUE),
                  B = rnorm(50))
demo$groups = rep(1:5, each=10)
demo.split = split(demo, demo$groups)
lapply(demo.split, colMeans)
# $`1`
#           A           B      groups 
# 165.9000000  -0.1530186   1.0000000 
# 
# $`2`
#           A           B      groups 
# 168.2000000   0.1141589   2.0000000 
# 
# $`3`
#           A           B      groups 
# 126.0000000   0.1625241   3.0000000 
# 
# $`4`
#           A           B      groups 
# 159.4000000   0.3340555   4.0000000 
# 
# $`5`
#           A           B      groups 
# 181.8000000   0.0363812   5.0000000
```

If you prefer to not add the groups to your source `data.frame`, you can achieve the same effect by doing the following:

```
groups = rep(1:5, each=10)
lapply(split(demo, groups), colMeans)
```

Of course, replace `colMeans` with whatever function you want.

Using your example of a `data.frame` with 1000 rows, your `rep()` statement should be something like:

```
rep(1:10, each=100)
```